# How to restrict a class (table) read only via cloud function?

Tags: parse-platform

I would like to have a class in Parse database which:

-is not readable via REST API or other platforms methods.
-is readable via Cloud function

This way I can be sure that only a user who has some private data inside table can read only the row which is belong to him/her. I can check required condition inside function. but its possible I do`nt know the objectId of that user yet and qualify him/her by some other data, so I can not use ACL to do this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the read access using CLP, then query via cloud code and passing the `{ useMasterKey: true }` option.